# How can I parse this text using regex (ruby)?

Tags: ruby, regex

http://services.tvrage.com/tools/quickinfo.php?show=Chuck

I'm trying to parse that info, for example, get the Airtime,

> Airtime@Monday at 08:00 pm

I want to get what's **after** "Airtime@" till the end of the line, to just come out with "Monday at 08:00 pm". How can I do this?

Comment: Oh MY GAWD. Please don't overcapitalize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason you don't use the XML feeds?

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

d = Nokogiri.XML(open 'http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/showinfo.php?sid=15614')

name = d.search('//showname').text               # => 'Chuck'
day  = d.search('//airday').text                 # => 'Monday'
time = d.search('//airtime').text                # => '20:00'
net  = d.search('//network[@country="US"]').text # => 'NBC'

puts "#{name} airs #{day}s at #{time} on #{net}."
# Chuck airs Mondays at 20:00 on NBC.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
result = allyourtextdata[/Airtime@(.+)/,1]
```

Or if you are also going to use some another strings from this report:

```
hash = Hash[allyourtextdata.scan(/(.+?)@(.+)/)]
p hash["Airtime"] # this will print "Monday at 08:00 pm"
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but it lead me the way! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'net/http'
url=URI.parse('http://services.tvrage.com/tools/quickinfo.php?show=Chuck')
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)
data=response.body
puts data.scan(/.*Airtime@(.*)\n/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why regex? Any problem getting substring?

```
s = "Airtime@Monday at 08:00 pm"
puts s[8..-1] # => Monday at 08:00 pm
```

**edit**
ok, this is for other options

```
puts s[s.index('@') + 1..-1]
```

Comment: Because there are other options aswell, such as "Show ID", ect.

Answer (score -1):

This is a great site for testing ruby regex expressions: http://rubular.com/